# How to answer interactive prompt that includes multiple answers per line

Tags: list, shell, fortran, prompt

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I am having trouble with a FORTRAN executable ("build" from Perple_X_6.8.5 in case anybody knows that) that requires input via prompts which I have to automate. For the prompts that only require one line as an answer I found the following solution:

```
./build << EOF
test                  `# Problem name deifnition`
hp02ver.dat           `# Declaration of the data base to be used`
perplex_option.dat    `# Declaration of the computational option file (default)`
N                     `# Tranform the data base components? (No)`
N                     `# Saturated fluids? (No)`
N                     `# Saturated components? (No)`
N                     `# chem. pot., activities, fugacities indipendet? (No)`
EOF
```

However, the next prompt gives me a list of components from which I have to chose:

```
Select thermodynamic components from the set:
NA2O  MGO   AL2O3   SIO2  K2O   CAO   TIO2  MNO   FEO   O2    H2O   CO2
Enter names, 1 per line, press <enter> to finish:
```

That is where the problem arises. How would I, following my initial solution for "simple" prompts, answer this prompt that requires one component per line a an "enter" in order to jump to the next prompt?

I tried the following:

```
./build << EOF
test                  `# Problem name deifnition`
hp02ver.dat           `# Declaration of the data base to be used`
perplex_option.dat    `# Declaration of the computational option file (default)`
N                     `# Tranform the data base components? (No)`
N                     `# Saturated fluids? (No)`
N                     `# Saturated components? (No)`
N                     `# chem. pot., activities, fugacities indipendet? (No)`
SIO2                  `# List of components`
TIO2
AL2O3
FEO
MNO
MGO
CAO
NA2O
K2O
H2O
EOF
```

which returned this error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Sequential READ or WRITE not allowed after EOF marker, possibly use REWIND or BACKSPACE
```

Please note that this is not the last prompt in the whole chain of prompts. More "simple" and more "list" prompts follow suit.

Comment: For those of us who are not familiar with this particular problem domain, would you say that you are trying to automatically fill in prompts using Fortran?

Comment: Try an empty line before EOF

Comment: You title is quite confusing but I think @WalterA is correct and should have wrirten an answer. Questions here should normally show some code, see [mcve].

Comment: @VladimirF I have posted it as an answer now. I did not have an oppurtunity for testing my answer with any code in the question, so I hesitated in posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First posted as a comment, but others think it is the answer)

The program asks for `Enter names, 1 per line, press <enter> to finish`.
Each line is finished with an `<enter>`, so here the program wants an additional `<enter>`.

Insert an empty line after the last thermodynamic component (before EOF or other input).

Comment: Thank you very much Walter A! It fixed the problem.